# I need a global variable in this application?

Tags: android

I have two Activities. Activity A have a button and a textview. Activity B have a listview. When I click the button in the activity A activity B is called with `startActivityforresult()`. When I click an item in the listview this element is deleted from the listview and `onActivityResult()` is called from activity A. When I click the button of the activity A, Activity B should not show the item previously deleted.
I need to use a global variable for store the list related to listview in this application?

Comment: [Read about Singleton](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_singleton.htm)

Comment: Are you are using a custom list adaptor?

Answer (score 0):

Using global variable is discouraged. But however if you want to make a variable available for all objects, you may use static variables.

Eg.

In MainActivity.java:

```
static String abc;
```

In Other Class:

```
String bcd = MainActivity.abc;
```